# CodeIgniter Model Locate Issue After Upload to server

Tags: php, codeigniter

After Hosting Php codeignitor website I Got a Error "Unable to locate the model you have specified: Common_model"
But Its Works in my local server 
How I can solve this issue 
I already change  First letter of the model class name capitalized  but no result 
my model class

```
class Common_model extends CI_Model 
{

}
```

and controller is

```
<?php   
class Show extends CI_Controller
{ var $pageLimit = 6;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('ion_auth');
        $this->load->model('common/Common_model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');    
        $this->load->helper('custom');
    }
}
```

Comment: where does "common" folder is located?

Comment: @jpganz18 under application\models\Common

Comment: Common_model must be inside the model not model/common

Comment: Second chk your file name as well must start with capital letter

Comment: By the way, maybe you should also take a look for this, would be a little cleaner way to do this, instead use folders inside a generic model folder https://github.com/jenssegers/codeigniter-hmvc-modules

Answer (score 2):

If you are are using Codeignitor 3 than make sure you file name also start with capital letter as:

```
Common_model.php
```

It's recommended to use your `models` inside the model folder not `model/anyfolder`

**[Codeignitor 3 Change Log User Manual](http://codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html)**

Comment: ,@Abdulla   yes after change application\models\Common\Common_model.php to application\models\Common_model.php its work fine but i have lot of models then how i can seperate it

Comment: Than what happened? @jishnu-chandran

Answer (score 2):

I hope Your model file structure is like

```
application
    model
        common
            Common_model.php
```

---

**File name** should be `Common_model.php`.

**Load in Controller** should be

```
$this->load->model('common_model');
```

Comment: If abdulla is here we will solve yur problm @jishnu-chandran

Comment: @jishnu-chandran if your issue has resolved than chose the best answer and mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I always load it with the name only, this way

```
$this->load->model('Common_model');
```

Always the controller is on the same module (if you are using modules)